# Not show image model in url background in ASP.NET Core

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using a ready-made html template, and I created one with ASP.NET Core 3.1.

Now I want to replace the images of the slides with the address of the images that from the bank in a `foreach`.

But when I do that, the images are not shown.

Ready template tag:

```
<";div class="slider-item" style="background-image: url(/SiteTemplate/assets/images/bg_2.jpg)>
```

I save my pictures in a folder `images/slidepic/wwwroot`. The items I tested are as follows:

```
<";div class="slider-item" style="background-image: url(/images/slidepic/@item.ImageSlider)>

<";div class="slider-item js-fullheight" style="background-image: url(@item.ImageSlider)>

class="slider-item" style="background-image:url('@Url.Content("~/images/slidepic" + item.ImageSlider) >   

<div class="slider-item" style="background-image:url('@Url.Content(item.ImageSlider)');">
```

Thank you for your guidance on what I should review and correct.
////////My code is

@model Models.ViewModels.HomeViewModel
@foreach (var item in Model.SlideList){
<div class="slider-item" style="background-image: url('@Url.Content("~/images/slidepic"+"/"+@item.ImageSlider)');">
}

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: Hi.Yes. But I Solve it  By another way.

Answer (score 1):

If your `Images` folder is under your `wwwroot` like following:

[image]

Then the url should be:

```
<div class="slider-item" style="background-image: url('@Url.Content("~/images/slidepic/aa.jpg")');">
```

If the `Images` folder is under your app project like following:

[image]

You need to do this change in your `startup`:

```
 app.UseStaticFiles();
 app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "Images")),
            RequestPath = "/Images"
        });
```

Then in your View:

```
<div class="slider-item" style="background-image: url('@Url.Content("/images/slidepic/aa.jpg")');">
```

You can see may demo below:

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new List<Image>
        {
          new Image
          {
              Name="aa.jpg"
          },
           new Image
          {
              Name="bb.jpg"
          },
            new Image
          {
              Name="cc.jpg"
          }
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

View:

```
@model List<Image>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="slider-item" style="background-image: url('@Url.Content("~/images/slidepic" +"/" + item.Name)');">
       @Html.DisplayFor(m=>item.Name)
    </div>
}
```

Test result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @sae ,You can try `<div class="slider-item" style="background-image: url('@Url.Content("~/images/slidepic" +"/" + item.ImageSlider)');">`

Comment: What is your `item.ImageSlider`?Is that a picture name like `aa.jpg`?

Comment: You can edit your case and add the part of foreach code in your view

Comment: Your picture is a background board, the <div> must contain other elements, otherwise the picture will not be displayed

Comment: You can see my demo.

Comment: If you only want to display the image,you can use code `<img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/slidepic" +"/" + item.ImageSlider)"/>`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I saw your demo . It's not work for me.

Comment: Try to reproduce my demo carefully.

Comment: I try. I don't want to dispaly in img tag, I want to palce in div as style backgroung url.and my <div> has other element like another <div> and <h2>,...